Add image layer to ecognition
Why, when I add an image layer to ecognition are the objects missing?
I have a ecognition project and I did multiresolution segmentation.
Now I want to add another image layer to project and clarify it, but when I add an image layer the objects missing. Is there any solution to prevent objects from being deleted?
